# Manage IIS Remotely through TFS2015

Tags: powershell, tfs-2015

Currently using TFS 2015 update 3 for deployments and I have added "PowerShell on target machine" task, which calls for PowerShell script saved on IIS server to stop website before deployments:

```
icm -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration; Stop-Website -Name $app}
```

with session variables as: `$server = abc.xyz.com`, `$app = DefaultWebSite`

The error I get is:

> The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.”

The same script works if I hard code the server & application name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a scriptblock, you can't use the variables from your script scope unless you use `param` with an argument list or with PowerShell 3+ use the `using:` scope modifier.

```
icm -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration; Stop-Website -Name $using:app}
```